# Nested for loops results in duplicate entries

Tags: php, for-loop, nested-loops

I have problems with the following code. I get duplicate entries of the content in the database.
I think it has something to do with the for loop, but I don't know how I could correct it.

SQL query:

```
  public function getConfRoomList()
  {
      $arr = array();
      $statement = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT id, name, roomnbr, location, seats, utilities from moterom order by name ASC");
      $statement->bind_result($id, $name, $roomnbr, $location, $seats, $utilities);
      $statement->execute();
      while ($statement->fetch()) {
      $arr[] = [ "id" => $id, "name" => $name, "roomnbr" => $roomnbr, "location" => $location, "seats" => $seats, "utilities" => $utilities];
      }
      $statement->close();

      return $arr;
  }

public function joinDevRoom()
  {
     $arr = array();
     $statement = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT r.name,GROUP_CONCAT(u.device) FROM moterom r LEFT JOIN utilities u ON FIND_IN_SET(u.id,r.utilities)>0 GROUP BY r.id");
     $statement->bind_result($id, $utilities);
     $statement->execute();
     while ($statement->fetch()) {
       $utilities = str_replace(',','<br />',$utilities);
       $arr[] = [ "id" => $id, "utilities" => $utilities];
     }
     $statement->close();

     return $arr;
  }

    public function getDeviceList()
    {
          $arr = array();
          $statement = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT id, device, model, img, supplier from utilities order by device ASC");
          $statement->bind_result($id, $device, $model, $img, $supplier);
          $statement->execute();
          while ($statement->fetch()) {
            $arr[] = [ "id" => $id, "device" => $device, "model" => $model, "img" => $img, "supplier" => $supplier];
          }
          $statement->close();

          return $arr;
    }
```

The content:

```
<?php
 require_once("db.php");
 $arr = $conn->getConfRoomList();
 $join = $conn->joinDevRoom();
 $dev = $conn->getDeviceList();
?>

<div class="add_dev_header">Møterom</div>
<?php
 if (!empty($arr)) { ?>

<table border='1'>
    <tr>
        <th>Conference room</th>
        <th>Room number</th>
    <th>Location</th>
    <th>Number of seats</th>
    <th>Available utilities</th>
    <th>Edit</th>
    <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
    <?php for( $i=0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
    for( $u=0; $u < count($join); $u++) {
    print_r  ("<tr>
     <td>".$arr[$i]['name']."</td>
     <td>".$arr[$i]['roomnbr']."</td>
   <td>".$arr[$i]['location']."</td>
   <td>".$arr[$i]['seats']."</td>
   <td>".$join[$u]['utilities']."</td>
   <td><a href='?p=editconfroomv2&id=".$arr[$i]['id']."'>Edit</a></td>
   <td><a href='?p=deleteconfroomdb&id=".$arr[$i]['id']."' class='delete'>Delete</a></td>
     </tr>"); } } ?>
</table>

<?php } else {
  echo "<div id='db_empty'>Database is empty...<br>
  You can be the first to <a href='?p=addconfroom'>register a conference room</a>.</div>";
}
?>
```

I have two rooms and one utility in the databases, and the printed result looks something like this:

Room 1 | Room number 1 | Location 1 | Seats 23 | Gear 1 | Edit | Delete
Room 1 | Room number 1 | Location 1 | Seats 23 | Gear 1 | Edit | Delete
Room 2 | Room number 2 | Location 2 | Seats 6 | Gear 1 | Edit | Delete
Room 2 | Room number 2 | Location 2 | Seats 6 | Gear 1 | Edit | Delete

Comment: If you have 2 rooms in `$arr` and 2 in `$join` you get 4 results. On a sidenote: this whole thing could be done with one query, saving you lots of code and problems like you encountered now.

Comment: Thank you for replying! How could I do this with one query?